# Track Google Ad Manager Revenue from BigQuery linked with GA4

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4, google-ad-manager

How can I query and calculate the total ad revenue per day from BigQuery, which is linked with GA4? I have successfully linked GA4 with BigQuery and I am receiving a set of events. However, I'm uncertain about which specific event pertains to ad revenue. My ultimate goal is to obtain the sum of ad revenue for each day through a query.

Tried LTV Revenue and returns NULL